# What does Debian (PHP-) package suffix `stable` mean and how to deal with it

Tags: php, debian, apt

TL;DR: `apt` on Debian 11.2 in a Docker container based on `php:7.3-apache` has `/stable` suffixed package names; dependencies cannot be resolved. How to install those packages (current problem `php7.3-dev`).

I'm trying to upgrade an older self-written application which currently runs in a Docker container (based on the official `php:7.3-apache` image which uses Debian 11.2) with PHP 7.3. There are some issues which I need to solve in order to continue upgrading to the next PHP version. To understand the root of the problem I would like to use Xdebug. Because `docker-php-ext-install` only supports PHP > 8.0 I need to compile Xdebug 3 by myself. To compile I need to install the `php-dev` package. Unfortunately when I run `apt udpate && apt search php7.3-dev` I only get `php7.3-dev/stable` package which I cannot install because it requires other packages which are referenced but without the `/stable` suffix. I already tried to add `https://packages.sury.org/` as source but then I get other suffixes.

I do not really understand how the packages get suffixed and why do they get suffixed. I would like to know this but only for learning reasons (which is a bonus).

How can I install `php-dev` in this case?